# JavaScript if statement suddenly stopped working

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am making a pong project right now, and I have a bit of code that lets changing directions be more smooth, so when you press both keys at the same time it won't freeze up for a moment. This happens in the *up()* function below.

```
let rx = 0;

pressDown = 
document.addEventListener('keydown', down);

pressUp = 
document.addEventListener('keyup', up);

function down(){
  if(event.keyCode === 39){
    rx = 3;

  }
  if(event.keyCode === 37){
    rx = -3;
  }
}
function up(){
  if (rx < 0 && event.keyCode === 37){
    rx = 0;
  }
  if (rx > 0 && event.keyCode === 39){
    rx = 0;
  }
}
```

It was working fine the other day, but when I opened my project this morning, this if statement suddenly did not work. The first part of the code does not work either until I change the second one by removing the `rx < 0` and `rx > 0`. I tried switching the `<` and `>` as well, but it did nothing. Does anyone have an answer or a solution?

Comment: Try adding `debugger` statements or `console.log`s in various parts to see what actually is executing (or not).

Comment: have you declared rx variable before using in if condition?

Comment: Keep in mind that `event` being a global variable is not true for every browser.  To work with all browsers, you should accept the event in as the first argument to your event handler.

Comment: Which `if` statement are you referring to, and in what way does it "not work"?  Try outputting the values to the console immediately before comparing them, and outputting the result of your comparison.  In what way does that result differ from what you expected?

Comment: Did you forgot to close ```down()``` just here or in your application code as well?

Comment: I only forgot to close ```down()``` here. Just fixed it.

Comment: Open devtools. Navigate to your code. Set a breakpoint at the first lines inside the functions. Press buttons. See if it breaks and step through the code to see what it does. Hover over variables to see their contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there are a few problems with your implementation:

1. You want the `down` and `up` function both to accept an `event` parameter (called `e` in my example).
2. Your `down` function had a missing closing brace. Not sure if that was a copy/paste error or if that was present in your original code.
3. The `rx` variable was never declared - maybe also a copy/paste error.

Take a look at the snippet I included below - it might be a helpful reference.

Good luck!

```js
let rx = 0;
const rxValueEl = $("#rx-value");

function down(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 39) {
    rx = 3;
  }
  
  if (e.keyCode === 37) {
    rx = -3;
  }

  // Sets value on page
  rxValueEl.html(rx);
}

function up(e) {
  if (rx < 0 && e.keyCode === 37) {
    rx = 0;
  }
  
  if (rx > 0 && e.keyCode === 39) {
    rx = 0;
  }

  // Sets value on page
  rxValueEl.html(rx);
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', down);
document.addEventListener('keyup', up);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>RX value:</p>
<p id="rx-value">0</p>

<p>Hit left + right arrows to change rx value</p>
```